# Symfony 2 - best approach for summing results of values in related entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

My code is aimed at getting items from database. Those item may have  either debit values or credit values. In template I present all of the values but would like also to provide information about sum of debit and account values connected with the account ($account_id)

**What would be your best practice how to do this?**

Should I simply run another two SQL queries:
first to SUM(value) where accountdebet = '.$account_id
secound to SUM(value) where accountcredit = '.$account_id?

Will it be the right approach?

```
Controller:
    // Get items for acccount and paginate
            $rp_items = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Items');
            $query = $rp_items->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.accountdebet = '.$account_id)
            ->orWhere('p.accountcredit = '.$account_id)
            ->getQuery();
            $rp_paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
            $db_pagination = $rp_paginator->paginate($query,$this->get('request')->query->getInt('page', 1),10);
            // Render TPL
            return $this->render('AppBundle:Accounts:items.html.twig', array('pagination' => $db_pagination, 'account' => $account));
```

In twig:

```
 {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

 {% block body %}
     <B>Item list for account {{ account.id }} </B><BR>

Account id: {{ account.id }}<BR>
Account marker: {{ account.marker }}<BR>
Account name: {{ account.name }}<BR>

<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
{# sorting of properties based on query components #}
    <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Id', 'a.id') }}</th>
    <th{% if pagination.isSorted('a.itemdate') %} class="sorted"{% endif %}>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Date', 'a.itemdate') }}</th>
    <th>Document</th>
    <th>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Marker', 'a.marker') }}</th>
    <th>Debit</th>
    <th>Credit</th>
</tr>

{# table body #}
{% for item in pagination %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <TD>{{ item.itemdate|date('Y-m-d')}}</TD>
    <td><A HREF="{{url('app_documents_details', {'id': item.documentid.id})}}">{{ item.documentid.marker }}</A></td>
    <td>{{ item.marker }}</td>

    <TD>{% if item.accountdebet.id == account.id %}
    {{ item.itemvalue}}
    {% endif %}
    </TD>
    <TD>{% if item.accountcredit.id == account.id %}
    {{ item.itemvalue}}
    {% endif %}</TD>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{# display navigation #}
<div class="pagination">
    {{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: don't you get insight from symfony2 debug bar?

Comment: My code does not result in error. I am looking for best way to sum up values.

Comment: Symfony2 debug bar is not only for errors. You also can review your application performance there.

Comment: I would have to test each solution that comes to my mind to check it. Thus, I am asking question here to find out how other do this. As this probably is common code to present result of query and sum up those results there probably are already developed solutions.

Comment: I didn't question your question, really. ;) It's fine to ask what you think necessary. Just want to share that Symfony2 debug bar could be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it in many ways but i like to make an parent entity eg ItemsCollection that holds an arrayCollection of Items. Then i give the new entity some extra functionality e.g.

```
public function countItemValues() 
{
   $total = 0;

   foreach($this->items as $item)
   {
       $total += $item->getValue();
   }

   return $total;
}
```

Comment: Af I would like to illiterate threw each Item in ItemsCollection would it still be good approach? I see that number of queries that doctrine does is gigantic.

Comment: Although i should not worrie to much about this you could write your own query to load the data at once if you are sure that it will not kill your server :p. For example i found this: https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql